# Running Command from Python. Works with os.system but not subprocces.run

Tags: python, subprocess

I have been on this problem for quite a while now. I have this command line that I want run trough python:

```
Users\name.lastname\Desktop\TESTER\Latitude 5431\Latitude-5431-46KCM_Win10_1.0_A01.exe /s /e=C:Users\name.lastname\Desktop\TESTER\Latitude 5431
```

this should run the .exe and then extract the files to the specified folder. I tried this with os.system and it worked but when I run it with

```
import subprocess
x = '"' + "\\Users\\name.lastname\\Desktop\\TESTER\\Latitude 5431\\Latitude-5431-46KCM_Win10_1.0_A01.exe" + '" ' + "/s /e=C:Users\\name.lastname\\Desktop\\TESTER\\Latitude 5431"
p1 = subprocess.run(x, shell=True)
```

it only shows me 'tips' like these but no error message and the .exe is not executed.

```
Pass command line arguments directly to vendor installer.

Turn the return code to success if required
Latitude-5431-46KCM_Win10_1.0_A01.exe /factoryinstall /passthrough D:\Sample.xml C:\log\FI.log


Change from the default log location to C:\my path with spaces\log.txt
Latitude-5431-46KCM_Win10_1.0_A01.exe /l="C:\my path with spaces\log.txt"

Force update to continue, even on "soft" qualification errors
Latitude-5431-46KCM_Win10_1.0_A01.exe /s /f
```

Comment: Please post the actual python code you are running. What you pasted above, will not execute.

Comment: ok did that @treuss

Comment: There are definitely quotes missing around your last argument (the one you pass with /e) as it contains a space. Additionally, your paths are not consistent, you use \Users for the program but C:Users for the argument. Most importantly, I would advise you against using `shell=True` here and just pass an array with the arguments, avoiding shell quoting issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try running without `shell=True` as it makes things more complicated than it helps:

```
import subprocess

prog = r"C:\Users\name.lastname\Desktop\TESTER\Latitude 5431\Latitude-5431-46KCM_Win10_1.0_A01.exe"
args = ["/s", r"/e=C:\Users\name.lastname\Desktop\TESTER\Latitude 5431"]

subprocess.run([prog]+args)
```

Comment: it works but I get the error that I need elevation. But running the same code with os.system does not give me this error code (WinError 740)